Execute insert query in TestContainers C#
I am doing a subcutaneous test with TestContainers.
My intention is to run a script to insert data, and then verify if it was indeed inserted. I run the source code with no errors, but when queried with Entity Framework, I get no information. If I fetch data with SqlConnection (ADO.NET) it does. Effectively in the container it is inserting all the data, only with EF I am not able to bring them, and I need obligatorily to use EF. It is as the data is being inserted but not refreshed (or something like that) What could it be?
It's NET 8, TestContainers with SqlServer, XUnit
[Fact]
public async Task Handle_ShouldSucceed()
{
    var query = File.ReadAllText("FakeData.sql");
    await DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(query, CancellationToken.None);
    var fakeTable = await DbContext.FakeTable.SingleOrDefaultAsync(v => v.Id == Guid.Parse("B98FD396-66D4-45A4-9247-9D5B4DB851E2"));
    fakeTable.Should().NotBeNull();
}


So what are the contents of the FakeData.sql file? Likely it contains something you can't use outside of SSMS or sqlcmd... such as GO batch seperators that aren't part of the T-SQL syntax.

Thanks @AlwaysLearning. This file only contains INSERT instructions without any other type. And indeed if the database is being populated thanks to this script

I'd assume that ID is different from the hardcoded one.

With ADO.NET it does work, the ID is correct
